# How to delete a file that starts with a -?

Tags: rm

I accidentally created a file when I meant to pass an option.  Now I have a file named: `-myfile` that I can not delete with `rm -myfile`

```
$ touch hi > -myfile
$ rm -myfile

rm: invalid option -- 'm'
Try 'rm ./-myfile' to remove the file ‘-myfile’.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Comment: This question is quite funny; since the posted error message already suggests one way to remove that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple, these are the two most common ways:

`rm ./-yourfile`

or

`rm -- -yourfile`